# How do I retrieve a child entity within Doctrine 2?

Tags: php, object, methods, doctrine-orm

Doctrine's entity manager appears to return an entity of the parent class under multi-table inheritance when the child entity is requested. This renders the child's methods and properties inaccessible.

I have two classes *person*(parent)->*owner*(child)

My code looks like this:

```
 $person = $entityManager->find('Library\Entity\People\Owner', 2);
```

This returns the parent(*person*) object not the requested *Owner* object.  I show how these entities are defined below.

**Question:** how do I get the entity manager to return the requested owner object with the shared id of 2 so I can access the *getOwnedProperty()* method?

The two entities are defined as follows - not sure if this is of any use in answering the question:

**FIRST ENTITY:** *person* (parent class)

```
namespace Library\Entity\People;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Library\Entity\General\Property;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection,    
Library\Entity\Contract\Tenantcontract,
Library\Entity\People\Owner;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Library\Repository\People\PersonRepository")  
 * @ORM\Table(name="Person") 
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr",type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "owner" = "Owner"})
 */
 class Person
{
 /**
 * @ORM\Id     
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer");     
 */
    protected $user_id = NULL;
}
```

**SECOND ENTITY:** *Owner*( a child of Person)

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity  
 */
 class Owner extends Person 
 {
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Library\Entity\General\Property",   mappedBy="owner_id")
*/
protected $ownedProperties = null;

public function __construct()
{
    $this -> ownerProperties = new ArrayCollection();       
}

public function addOwnedProperty($propertyId)
{
    $this -> ownedProperties[] = $propertyId;   
}

public function getOwnedProperty()
{
    return $this -> ownedProperties; 
}   
 }
```

Comment: You should use the relations - within models define `@HasMany` or `@HasOne` relation from Person to Model and vice versa, then You can retrieve the owner object easily calling `$person->owner`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `discr` column in your `Person` table for the user_id is "owner" and that there is a corresponding row with id 2 in the `owner` table?

Comment: @shadyyx this is probably a practical work around, but I was hoping to figure out inheritance as in the data model an owner and a person are the same entity, not just related in the way for instance an owner and a possession are.

Comment: @Tomdarkness great question! The issue is not the one I thought I was facing. #2 is indeed a person not an owner.  The issue seems to be that doctrine returns a person (with an id of 2) if there is no owner with that id.  Next steps - I need first to recheck my code entering owner data in mysql, and include a check in my script to ensure that only an owner is passed back or an error thrown to provide an alert that the person is not in the owner category. Many thanks, feel free to write up if you want me to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a repository for the child class:

```
class Owner extends Person 
{
    @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Library\Repository\People\**Owner**Repository")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue with doctrine returning the parent class relates to how doctrine handles a call for a person that is not an owner (i.e. part of the parent class, but not the child class)

If you request the child class (owner) doctrine will return an instance of the parent class if there is an parent entity with the specified id.

My initial expectation was that doctrine would instead fail to return an entity.

While this is not a problem in and of itself it is useful to be aware of how doctrine treats these calls to ensure adequate safeguards are inserted into your code.